# Add clickable element within a clickable table row

Tags: javascript, angular-ui

Let's say I have a table row with a clickable element in it:

```
  <tr ng-repeat="product in products" onclick="showProductDetail()">
      <td>{{product.id}}</td>
      <td>{{product.title}}</td>
      <td>{{product.price}}</td>
      <td>
        <switch id="enabled" name="enabled" ng-model="product.enabled" ng-change="enableProduct()"></switch>
      </td>
  </tr>
```

I'm using [Angular UI Switch](https://github.com/xpepermint/angular-ui-switch) but the issue would be the same for any clickable element.

How do I make the row clickable but isolate the behavior of the switch? Currently it tries to do both, resulting in wonky behavior. I know I could just make each cell except that last one clickable, but is there a cleaner way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Dmitry's answer does not work.

Try calling the ng-change with `enableProduct($event)`

And within that function, call

```
function enableProduct($event) {
   $event.stopPropagation();
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the `<switch>` handler should stop the event propagation. Try to return `false` from you `ng-change` handler. E.g.

```
ng-change="enableProduct(); return false"
```